# Can't debug Rust within VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I have installed the C\C++ Windows extension. The my_project.vscode\launch.json looks like this;

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/my_project.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run I get

```
Error processing 'configurationDone' request. Unable to start the Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console.
```

The Debug Console is showing at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Maybe try to use `"console": "integratedTerminal"`or `"internalConsole"`. To me this sounds like the current configuration tries to launch the Visual Studio (not Code) Terminal and Visual Studio maybe is not installed.

Comment: I had this problem a year ago, then it vanished on it's own after 2 months of not touching VSCode. Now I'm having it again. It's ridiculous.